# Why is the life of the Jews in the concentration camp on the projector shown as very beautiful?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-boy-in-the-striped-pyjamas

*The Boy in the Striped Pyjamas* features a scene where the higher rank officers come to meet Bruno's dad, and over the projector it was shown the privileges the Jews have in the concentration camps, which Bruno sees while climbing the gate.

So what exactly did it convey? That Germans wanted to give a good life to Jews in the concentration camp which they never got?

Comment: I would put it more in the category of propaganda. Those in charge have always sought to show others - as well as the captives - that those imprisoned have it better off than they actually do. North Korea would be an excellent example. Alternatively, as a certain dragon once said, "Why chase down your food when you can convince them to walk right into your mouth?"

Comment: @Omegacron : Beautifully explained :).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the Nazi's master plan was to kill all the Jews. It was easier to do if they 1) hid the plan and 2) got the Jews to cooperate in the plan. So they lied, to the Jews, to other Germans, to the World. They pretended the Jews were just being relocated. Then they pretended they were just prisoners of war. Then they marched them into a "shower" where they gassed them all without them knowing it.

The projected film is pure, unadulterated propaganda, intended to make their final solution easier to happen.